# CodeIgniter Session equal to Internet Banking

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have an application developed with CodeIgniter, PHP and MySQL. The session of the user always worked according to CodeIgniter default behavior, however, now I need the session to be more restrictive, working equal a internet banking session, expiring in seven minutes (420 seconds) inactivity, while each request of the client for the server these seven minutes are be removed.

I don't know if natively just defining the parameters the CodeIgniter offers Support for that form of store the session, however I'm not able to represent that form of work.

I don't know if for this level of restriction I need to override some methods of the classes CI_Session, or if only just set correctly the parameters of CI?

If already exists some classes or plugin of CodeIgniter who can help me with it?

Example of my parameters:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 420; 
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']          = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']            = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent']         = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']          = 420;
$config['sess_storage']                 = 'database';
$config['sess_database']                = 'default';
$config['sess_timeout']                 = 7200;
$config['sess_destroy_on_timeout']      = FALSE;
$config['sess_update_interval']         = 180;
$config['sess_gc_probability']          = 10;
$config['sess_http_only']               = FALSE;
$config['sess_secure']                  = FALSE;
$config['sess_forwarded_ip']            = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well according to the Codeigniter session guide there are following Session related preferences which are as follow

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 420;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 420;
```

[image: Session preference table according Codeigniter user guide]

Now how it works is when user come to the website Codeigniter assign the user a unique session id which you can check by using this function `echo $this->session->userdata('session_id');` so it will show you current session id now coming to the point if you want to set the session only for 7 second it can be your defined session or session which automatically generated by codeigniter it self it will be expire every 7 second and will generate a new session to the user who is navigating site.

**Note:** *if you are working with customer on shoping cart or e cart don't put a little time for expiration of session it will cause huge problem for you*

Comment: Thank you! I did change my config.php removing the unnecessary properties as suggested by you, and the session behavior became to more predictable.